# SQL - how do I insert into these tables?

Tags: sql-insert

```
 create table Employees
 (
       EmployeeID INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
       EmployeeName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
       EmployeeUsername VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
       EmployeeEmail VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
       GroupID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TypeOfGroup(GroupID),
       Password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
 );

 create table TypeOfGroup
 (
       GroupID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
       TypeGroup VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
       Permission CHAR(1) NOT NULL
 );
```

Question: I have a foreign key and wanted to make a connection with another table as I do this to insert into.

My foreign key is 'GROUPID'.

Comment: What do u want exactly....

Comment: I want  Insert Into

Comment: in which table???

Comment: IN  table employees

Comment: I know this Insert Into is not right but I don't know why?                 INSERT INTO Employees(EmployeeName, EmployeeUsername, EmployeeEmail, GroupID,Password)?
VALUES
('ANA', 'ana', 'ana@email.com', (SELECT GroupID from TypeGroup WHERE GroupID='1'), '123'),
('DIOGO', 'diogo', 'diogo@email.com', (SELECT GroupID from TypeGroup WHERE GroupID='2'), '123'),
('CATARINA', 'catarina', 'catarina@email.com', (SELECT GroupID from TypeGroup WHERE GroupID='3'), '123');

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
insert into TypeOfGroup( TypeGroup, Permission) values ('hr', 1)
```

"this 1 is used for bit which is a data type in sql server 1 for true and 0 for false"

```
 insert into Employees (EmployeeName, EmployeeUsername, EmployeeEmail, 
 GroupID, Password) values ('bruno', 'bruno', 'bruno@gmail.com', 1, 'urPassword')
```

and 1 in the 2nd query is primary of typeofgroup table.